# access function on stateful widget from class outside

Tags: flutter

I'm using Workmanager to keep calling a function in the background of my application. It says I need a top-level function, so I'm calling outside any stateful widget, but I need to call a function that uses a context because I'm using a provider. I was wondering if there's a way to call a function declared inside a widget a top-level function.

`showNotification` function uses a provider, so I'm using a context, but I need to call it on the function `callbackDispatcher`. 
Here's part of my code:

```
 void main() {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher);
 }
 
 //top level function
 void callbackDispatcher() {
   Workmanager().executeTask((taskName, inputData) {
     showNotification('05/22/2023'); //the function i need to call
     return Future.value(true);
   });
 }
 
 class App extends StatefulWidget {
   const App({
     super.key,
   });
 
   @override
   State<App> createState() => _AppState();
 }
 
 class _AppState extends State<App> {
 
   //function i need to call from my top level function
   showNotification(String date) {
     Provider.of<NotificationService>(context, listen: false).showNotification(
       CustomNotification(
         id: 1,
         title: 'You have an appointment.',
         body: 'Don't forget your appointment on the day $date',
         payload: AppRoutes.PATIENT_INFO,
       ),
     );
   }
 }
```